# Comparing Lua toNumber to JS parseInt - results don't match

Tags: javascript, node.js, lua, fivem

I'm converting a Lua script for FiveM into JavaScript (NodeJS platform) and I've ran into a bizarre issue that I cannot get my head around.

The functionality I am converting is simple, it takes a FiveM identifer (the user's steamid as recorded by fivem) and converts it from hexadecimal to decimal. It then passes the decimal value to the steam web API so we can parse the json response for profile name/avatar etc.

The code itself works fine. The issue likes with the conversion. for obvious reasons I cannot post API key's or steam ID's so I'll blank it out for demonstrating.

In LUA:

```lua
local steamid = tonumber(tempSteam,16)
```

retrieves the hex steam id and converts to dec.

In JS:

```
var steamid = parseInt(tempSteam,16);
```

The JS equivalent to the above.

The weird thing is this. Passing in the tempSteam in JS results in a steamid ending ###0, this does not match my profile which ends ###6 (all other digits are identical).

EDIT: Cut explanation content, I have since found out (thanks to comments) that JS cannot convert 64bit values. So I now need to find a workaround.

Comment: `when I run it through w3schools "try it yourself" for parseInt() I get the same incorrect value ###0.`  - How to reproduce this error?  Give an example (you can modify your real steam ID) please.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parseint I went here, and inside one of the lines I replaced the string content with my tempSteam, which is a hexadecimal string. Then I clicked "run" at the top and "try it" in the html result panel. This then outputs the parseInt conversion

Comment: What hex string should I insert there to reproduce the bug?

Comment: If your hex string is a 64 bit number, then JS is unable to convert it - JS numbers are `double` (up to 53 integer bits)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have found a hex value to use from a tutorial and tested it, please see my edits for example. Hex value is `110000103d27e1d `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments for the unknown information, I was not aware that JS was not capable natively of dealing with 64 bit numbers.

I have found a solution so I am posting it here in case anyone else runs into this issue.

NodeJS 10+ has a new `BigInt` function, which can convert the hex values to a 64bit signed integer.

```
// Our steamhex variable, this is normally pulled via FiveM's identifiers 
// so this const is just to demonstrate what it is. 
// The 0x is important, without it the BigInt function seems to fail with a 
// generic `cannot convert`.
const steamHex = '0x110000103d27e1d';

//If using fiveM use a replace i.e 
//steamHex = steamHex.replace('steam:','0x');

//Returns 76561198024392221
var result = BigInt(steamHex); 

//...pop result into your steam api call etc....
```